# Issue regarding displaying forge dataset using mglearn

Tags: python

Code Doesn't run even though mglearn is installed. What's the issue? Probably something wrong with importing mglearn.

```
import mglearn
X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
# plot dataset
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], y)
plt.legend(["Class 0", "Class 1"], loc=4)
plt.xlabel("First feature")
plt.ylabel("Second feature")
print("X.shape: {}".format(X.shape))
```

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 import mglearn
      2 X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
      3 # plot dataset

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mglearn\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from . import plots
      2 from . import tools
      3 from .plots import cm3, cm2

Comment: Which operating system? How did you install mglearn?